# Filter out words like "sex" from questions

Tags: support, feature-request

Yesterday night, I saw a post with title ["Bangladeshi Narayanganj Women's Parlor Owner Jharna Real Sex Scandal Part -"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42600515/bangladeshi-narayanganj-womens-parlor-owner-jharna-real-sex-scandal-part) (now deleted).

I flagged it for moderator intervention, and it was removed within 5-6 minutes. But for that timespan, the question was active on the site.

I think words "sex" and "scandal" should be added to the *bad word* dictionary.

Comment: Spam is a big problem that is constantly being dealt with. Some times of the day are quicker than others for getting rid of spam.

Comment: Promotion of porn contents is dangerous for such a community and it should be treated with more careful than spam

Comment: It is spam and we all deal with it as a community, alongside the built in systems and systems written by the community. To say we are doing more than could be reasonably expected would be an understatement. Yes some things last a bit longer than we would ultimately like, it isn't a perfect world, and we get an unreasonably large amount of spam. Honestly it's a wonder the site isn't completely overrun with spam.

Comment: Can I assume the downvoters support promoting and posting such contents in SO?

Comment: I haven't voted on this question, but I would assume that the downvoters are expressing that they disagree such words should be automatically blocked. You have been presented with reasoning as to why they should not be automatically blocked, given that both words can exist in real questions and are only obscene in certain circumstances.

Comment: Yes, I want to see porn on Stack Overflow. That's why I downvoted this question. It's the only reasonable explanation.

Comment: great words to hear.

Comment: Seriously though, what exactly about that post is worse than any other piece of spam? Spammers can't post images, nor links. They can just use words. In the western world, the words "sex" and "scandal" are already used gratuitously in everyday media; a cursory Google search shows that the same is the case at least in some parts of India, too.

Comment: I disagree with your premise that either word in "sex scandal" is, in and of itself, "bad". You appear to have confused that post being problematic (it was, but was swiftly dealt with in the usual manner) with those words being somehow unacceptable in any context (they are not). For example, imagine you were building a Twitter bot to map the spread of scandalous news; how do you ask about those? *"Can I assume the downvoters support promoting and posting such contents in SO?"* - you *could*, we can't really stop you, but I don't think that it's an intelligent assumption to make.

Comment: Also it's hilarious that the post in question was tagged [tag:premature-optimization].

Comment: I downvoted this because it was poorly researched, is not useful, and should not be implemented.

Answer (score 32):

These would not be good words to blacklist. The site has only a very small number of blacklisted words, for good reasons. Blacklisting input adds a large burden to the servers and makes it harder for users to post questions and answers that might well be legitimate.

It is entirely plausible that someone could use the words "sex" or "scandal" legitimately in a question. See, for example, [these 16,026 posts containing the word "sex"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sex) without being obscene. Most of them use the word in the (very common) sense of distinguishing between males and females. There's no need to block the use of the word in those contexts.<sup>*</sup>

As a more general point: spam gets deleted very quickly in nearly all instances on here. The current system works pretty well, so you would need to identify a major, recurring problem to justify adding a blacklist rule. A single, bad post that lasted barely 5 minutes isn't a sign that the system is broken.

Also, as [Machavity said in another answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2370483/machavity), use the spam flag, not a generic mod flag. The spam flag is appropriate for the post you mentioned, and it allows the community to handle problem posts much more efficiently.

<sup>* For what it's worth, there are also [92 posts containing the word "scandal"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=scandal), and, again, these are not spammy posts. There's even [a post containing the exact phrase "sex scandal" as part of a string to be analyzed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37915597/are-those-stringi-and-string-same-fieldtype) and [another containing it as a joke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30037045/performant-search-in-listview/30038113#30038113), and they're not spam, either.</sup>

Answer (score 12):

While it's cool you mod flagged it, the better response here is to **spam flag**. Mod flags depend on mods. Spam flags actually don't need to wait on a mod. Once the threshold of flags is met (from any users), the Community user will delete the post and flag the account for mods to investigate.

I've let the Charcoal team (a non-SE group of people who fight spam) know about this (doesn't look like Smoke Detector caught it)

Comment: Fine. But in my opinion, we don't have to use the 2 words I mentioned in question in a programming related site. Am I correct?

Comment: Like I said, I let the Charcoal team know. They have a spam flag bot and lots of folks spam flag questions like the one you noted

Comment: Ok. That was a great movement

Comment: @SagarV I'd suggest doing a search with the words, to see how many legit questions have them.

Comment: @SagarV thanks for reporting the post, I have blacklisted the keywords 'sex scandal' with the SmokeDetector bot so that we will catch posts like this in future to have them swiftly deleted. If you'd like to know more or help out, feel free to join us [in our chatroom Charcoal HQ](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq)